# The custom 500 error page not working in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, error-handling, web-config, asp.net-mvc-5, custom-error-pages

Here is my web.config custom errors configuration:

```
<system.web>
 <customErrors mode="On" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite" defaultRedirect="~/400.aspx">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/404.aspx" />
  <error statusCode="500" redirect="~/500.aspx" />
  <error statusCode="400" redirect="~/400.aspx" />
</customErrors>
</system.web>
    <system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
      <remove statusCode="404"/>
      <error statusCode="404" path="404.html" responseMode="File"/>
      <remove statusCode="500"/>
      <error statusCode="500" path="500.html" responseMode="File"/>
      <remove statusCode="400"/>
      <error statusCode="400" path="400.html" responseMode="File"/>
    </httpErrors>
 </system.webServer>
```

Works fine for 404.
But this localhost:44303/< script >< /script > returns: Runtime Error.

As well throwing a new Exception from an action intentionally redirects to mvc error page, which I want to override with my 500.aspx

Answer (score 3):

After some research into the source code for the `HandleErrorAttribute` that is added as a global filter, there is code that tries to force application to use the MVC Error page.

So what I did was subclass the `HandleErrorAttribute` and effectively reverse that line:

```
public class MyHandleErrorAttribute : HandleErrorAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnException(filterContext);

        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = false;
    }
}
```

Then replace the code in the App_Start/FilterConfig.cs to use the new MyHandleErrorAttribute:

```
filters.Add(new MyHandleErrorAttribute());
```

This should prevent MVC from overriding your custom 500 page.